# How do I finetune a Whisper ASR model by streaming the common_voice dataset?

Tags: python, audio-streaming, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets, openai-whisper

I am trying to download a huge voice dataset from Huggingface. To avoid the disk space usage,trying to download the data in Streaming Mode. Everything goes fine, until the time reaches training the model.

```
common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "en", split="train", use_auth_token=True,streaming=True)
.
.
.

batch['labels'] = tokenizer(text=batch['text']). input_ids
.
.
.
.

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    args=training_args,
    model=model,
    train_dataset=Dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=Dataset['train'],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor,)


Trainer.train()
```

Its giving an error "You need to specify either `text` or `text_target`." from 'tokenization_utils_base.py. Even after I have given the labels in 'text' or "text_target" in tokenizer still I am facing this issue.

Tried updating the Tokenizer as `tokenizer(text=batch['text'])` or `tokenizer(text_target=batch['text']`.  But still facing the same issue.

Any help on this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It's hard to debug without the full code and the goal/purpose that you want your code to achieve. Looking at the screenshot, it looks like you are trying to fine-tune whisper with common_voice dataset? Is that that goal? Also, please add in the ... to help us help you find what's wrong. And also please post the error message in text in the question rather than the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was using own wav files and common voice for fine tune the whisper model. While debugging I realized both are using different columns and got into contradiction while tokenizing the sentences.

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

Scroll down to the part of the answer that has the code before  "**It works!**"

Or jump to the pudding: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10wUT2MtmWnrEEHKfBsAu0TWXQazOo4Be?usp=sharing

---

## In Long

It's hard to debug without the full code and the goal/purpose that you want your code to achieve. Looking at the screenshot, it looks like you are trying to fine-tune whisper with common_voice dataset.

Thus, here goes some tips that might help...

#### Me: Start experimenting with smaller dataset

To better understand the full end-to-end data processing (ETL) -> `trainer.train()` process, I'll suggest using smaller language as a start **WITHOUT** streaming feature.

Starting from the README: https://huggingface.co/datasets/common_voice

Then some exploratory (EDA) code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

# Lets try with Tamil.
common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "ta", split="train")

audio_vector = common_voice[0]['audio']['array']
sent = common_voice[0]['sentence']

print(sent)
print(audio_vector)
print(audio_vector.shape)
```

[out]:

```
அவரைப் பொதுமக்கள் விடாமல் பின்னாலேயே துரத்திக் கொண்டே ஓடினார்கள்.
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
(393984,)
```

Lets try another data point:

```
audio_vector = common_voice[1]['audio']['array']
sent = common_voice[1]['sentence']
print(sent)
print(audio_vector)
print(audio_vector.shape)
```

[out]:

```
மனிதனுடைய இன்பங்கள் இரண்டு வகை.
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
(267840,)
```

#### You: So the length of the decoded audio vector is different size. Then how can we train any consistent models for every data point?

Lets read the README again (more carefully), explaining the `audio` part of the common_voice dataset:

> **audio:** A dictionary containing the path to the downloaded audio file, the decoded audio array, and the sampling rate. Note that when accessing the audio column: dataset[0]["audio"] the audio file is automatically decoded and resampled to dataset.features["audio"].sampling_rate. Decoding and resampling of a large number of audio files might take a significant amount of time. Thus it is important to first query the sample index before the "audio" column, i.e. dataset[0]["audio"] should always be preferred over dataset["audio"][0].

```
print(common_voice[0]['audio'])
print()
print(common_voice[1]['audio'])
```

[out]:

```
{'path': '/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads/extracted/632b3eb1435158228029bc5172c7ebd3ea99f1ec6eefc20631a0e783e206f951/common_voice_ta_26650298.mp3', 
'array': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32),
 'sampling_rate': 48000}

{'path': '/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads/extracted/632b3eb1435158228029bc5172c7ebd3ea99f1ec6eefc20631a0e783e206f951/common_voice_ta_26650300.mp3',
 'array': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32),
 'sampling_rate': 48000}
```

#### You: There's this `sampling_rate` thing, what do I do with it?

If you have some cash to spend on ChatGPT API, you could ask it. Or simply https://www.google.com/search?q=sampling+rate+audio+definition =)

[image]

#### You: Stop distracting me, I just want to train a Seq2Seq model

Yes, but if you don't have a standardized input to feed to the encoder, the model will be doing [GIGO training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

#### Me: Okay, okay, so we have to find someway to use the audio array and sampling rate to create a "representation" of the audio

In speech processing, MFCC) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum

> The mel-frequency cepstrum is a representation of the short-term power spectrum of a sound, based on a linear cosine transform of a log power spectrum on a nonlinear mel scale of frequency. Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients are coefficients that collectively make up an MFC.
>
> Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients (MFCCs) are coefficients that collectively make up an MFC. They are derived from a type of cepstral representation of the audio clip (a nonlinear "spectrum-of-a-spectrum"). - Wikipedia

#### Q: That's a lot of mambo-jambo, what does that MFCC even mean in the context of machine learning and training a Seq2Seq model?

A: TL;DR, it just means you can convert the raw audio inputs represented by the decoded audio array and sampling rate into a fixed-size vector representation of the audio.

- In the context of computer-vision, think converting an image into the RGB representation into a fixed size matrix
- In the context of NLP, think converting any input sentence/word into a fixed size vector/matrix.
- In the context of speech processing, think converting the audio file into MFCC, i.e. a fixed size vector

There is a preprocessor in the Huggingface `transformers` library that processes an audio-array with its sampling rate into the MFCC representation.

#### To process the audio array in `common_voice` to fine-tune a `whisper` model

See https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/whisper#transformers.WhisperFeatureExtractor

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "ta", split="train")

feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny"
)

example = common_voice[0]['audio']

# While the max sampling rate of the audio is 48000, 
# it might be too computationally expensive, 
# so we can down sample it to default 16K from the WhisperFeatureExtractor object.

extracted_feature_0 = feature_extractor(common_voice[0]['audio']['array'], sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]
extracted_feature_1 = feature_extractor(common_voice[1]['audio']['array'], sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]

print(extracted_feature_0.size, extracted_feature_1.size)
print(extracted_feature_0)
```

[out]:

```
240000 240000
[[-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]
 [-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]
 [-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]
 ...
 [-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]
 [-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]
 [-0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723 ... -0.5615723 -0.5615723 -0.5615723]]
```

#### You: காத்திருங்கள் (Wait a minute), I understand now how the representation processing works but what has it got to do with my error message?!

Me: Before going back to your original question, here's 2nd part of the data that you are interested in when training a Seq2Seq model with the `common_voice` data

#### To process the sentence input in common_voice

Since it looks like you are trying to fine-tune a whisper model, the tokenizer you need to process the sentence input should also come from the whisper model, i.e. https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/whisper#transformers.WhisperTokenizer

In code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "ta", split="train")

feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny"
)

tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny", 
     language="Tamil",
     task="transcribe",
     model_max_length=225
)

examples = [common_voice[0]['sentence'], common_voice[1]['sentence']]

print(tokenizer(examples, max_length=225, truncation=True).input_ids)
```

[out]:

```
[ 
  [50258, 50299, 50359, 50363, 878, 227, 36001, 8402, 8012, 2133, 12008, 19433, 4742, 3923, 6980, 4234, 2133, 15094, 2133, 13535, 4516, 6421, 5036, 6980, 6993, 2133, 12008, 4516, 5511, 2133, 5511, 5036, 6993, 10478, 8491, 10478, 18198, 3923, 6467, 4742, 2133, 4742, 4516, 4234, 2133, 13786, 19433, 15297, 2133, 6421, 10478, 2548, 241, 6421, 4516, 5511, 5036, 6467, 2133, 15094, 14969, 50257], 

  [50258, 50299, 50359, 50363, 6980, 5511, 4516, 4742, 5511, 3923, 6421, 8402, 8491, 12894, 5511, 2133, 8012, 17167, 2133, 15094, 2133, 26277, 15297, 2133, 6421, 3923, 13535, 4234, 48993, 50257]
]
```

#### You: Stop stalling! Tell me how to feed the data into the `Seq2SeqTrainer`!

Alright, alright, *“patience you must have; have patience and all will be revealed,*.

#### Using dataset with map function

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "ta", split="train")

feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny"
)

tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny", 
     language="Telugu",
     task="transcribe",
     model_max_length=225
)

def process(batch):
    # Convert audio array to MFCC
    batch["input_features"] = feature_extractor(batch["audio"]["array"], sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]
    # Convert text inputs to token ids
    batch["labels"] = tokenizer(batch["sentence"], max_length=225, truncation=True).input_ids
    return batch

# Lets just try the processor on the first 10 data points.
common_voice = common_voice.select(range(10))

common_voice = common_voice.map(process)

# Lets take a look at the first processed data
print(common_voice[0])
```

[out]:

```
{'client_id': 'a1252dd9f1a6c970da7b1a330ad07f9546330b5007dcd8db52ae3ac6774fb3d9150bc117b4df1944d7899d3ab8325cb03217c4797dec1627d1ad83eea7509d41',
 'path': '/root/.cache/huggingface/datasets/downloads/extracted/632b3eb1435158228029bc5172c7ebd3ea99f1ec6eefc20631a0e783e206f951/common_voice_ta_26650298.mp3',
 'audio': {'path': None,
  'array': array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]),
  'sampling_rate': 48000},
 'sentence': 'அவரைப் பொதுமக்கள் விடாமல் பின்னாலேயே துரத்திக் கொண்டே ஓடினார்கள்.',
 'up_votes': 2,
 'down_votes': 0,
 'age': 'fifties',
 'gender': 'female',
 'accent': '',
 'locale': 'ta',
 'segment': '',
 'input_features': [[-0.5615723133087158,
   ...]],
 'labels': [50258,
  ...]}
```

##### You: That's all good but how do I do it with English and streaming?

*Patience, my blue friend*. Now that you have the processor code working with a smaller dataset, lets try to first feed it into the `Seq2SeqTrainer` before leaping into larger and streaming data set.

Lets piece up how the data is processed with

- compute_metrics
- data collator
- Seq2SeqTrainer() initialization
- trainer.train()

##### Most probably this will also patch the missing code/information in the original question

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration, Seq2SeqTrainer
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer


feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny"
)

tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny", 
     language="Tamil",
     task="transcribe",
     model_max_length=225
)

def process(batch):
    # Convert audio array to MFCC
    batch["input_features"] = feature_extractor(batch["audio"]["array"], sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]
    # Convert text inputs to token ids
    batch["labels"] = tokenizer(batch["sentence"], max_length=225, truncation=True).input_ids
    return batch

# As for the data collator, you can reuse this from
# https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/speech-recognition/run_speech_recognition_seq2seq.py#L224
@dataclass
class DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding:
    processor: Any

    def __call__(self, features):
        # split inputs and labels since they have to be of different lengths and need
        # different padding methods
        model_input_name = self.processor.model_input_names[0]
        input_features = [{model_input_name: feature[model_input_name]} for feature in features]
        label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]

        batch = self.processor.feature_extractor.pad(input_features, return_tensors="pt")

        labels_batch = self.processor.tokenizer.pad(label_features, return_tensors="pt")

        # replace padding with -100 to ignore loss correctly
        labels = labels_batch["input_ids"].masked_fill(labels_batch.attention_mask.ne(1), -100)

        batch["labels"] = labels

        return batch

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", "ta")

# Lets just try the processor on the first 10 data points.
common_voice_train = common_voice['train'].select(range(10))
common_voice_train = common_voice_train.map(process)

# Lets just try the processor on the first 5 data points.
common_voice_valid = common_voice['validation'].select(range(5))
common_voice_valid = common_voice_valid.map(process)


# Set the model 
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-tiny")
# Set the processor
processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small", language="Tamil", task="transcribe")
# Set the data collator
data_collator = DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding(processor=processor)

metric = evaluate.load("wer")

def compute_metrics(pred):
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    label_ids = pred.label_ids

    # replace -100 with the pad_token_id
    label_ids[label_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id

    # we do not want to group tokens when computing the metrics
    pred_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    label_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(label_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    wer = 100 * metric.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str)

    return {"wer": wer}

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=common_voice_train,
    eval_dataset=common_voice_valid,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor, 
)

trainer.train()
```

## It works!

#### You: Hmmm, alright, so when I copy and paste the code above it works, what about streaming the data and English?

Try changing this portion of the code:

```
LANGUAGE = "Tamil"
STREAMING = False

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", LANGUAGE[:2].lower(), streaming=STREAMING)

# And also change the Tokenizer / Processor appropriately.
```

Then you'll get:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

from datasets import load_dataset
import evaluate
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration, Seq2SeqTrainer
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer
from transformers import WhisperFeatureExtractor, WhisperTokenizer


LANGUAGE = "Tamil"
STREAMING = True

feature_extractor = WhisperFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny"
)

tokenizer = WhisperTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-tiny", 
     language=LANGUAGE,
     task="transcribe",
     model_max_length=225
)

def process(batch):
    # Convert audio array to MFCC
    batch["input_features"] = feature_extractor(batch["audio"]["array"], sampling_rate=16000).input_features[0]
    # Convert text inputs to token ids
    batch["labels"] = tokenizer(batch["sentence"], max_length=225, truncation=True).input_ids
    return batch

# As for the data collator, you can reuse this from
# https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/speech-recognition/run_speech_recognition_seq2seq.py#L224
@dataclass
class DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding:
    processor: Any

    def __call__(self, features):
        # split inputs and labels since they have to be of different lengths and need
        # different padding methods
        model_input_name = self.processor.model_input_names[0]
        input_features = [{model_input_name: feature[model_input_name]} for feature in features]
        label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]

        batch = self.processor.feature_extractor.pad(input_features, return_tensors="pt")

        labels_batch = self.processor.tokenizer.pad(label_features, return_tensors="pt")

        # replace padding with -100 to ignore loss correctly
        labels = labels_batch["input_ids"].masked_fill(labels_batch.attention_mask.ne(1), -100)

        batch["labels"] = labels

        return batch

common_voice = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_11_0", LANGUAGE[:2].lower(), streaming=STREAMING)


# Set the model 
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-tiny")
# Set the processor
processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small", language=LANGUAGE, task="transcribe")
# Set the data collator
data_collator = DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding(processor=processor)

metric = evaluate.load("wer")

def compute_metrics(pred):
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    label_ids = pred.label_ids

    # replace -100 with the pad_token_id
    label_ids[label_ids == -100] = tokenizer.pad_token_id

    # we do not want to group tokens when computing the metrics
    pred_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    label_str = tokenizer.batch_decode(label_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    wer = 100 * metric.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str)

    return {"wer": wer}

# You need this when using streaming.
args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(output_dir="my-model/", max_steps=100)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=common_voice['train'].map(process),
    eval_dataset=common_voice['validation'].map(process),
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor,
)

trainer.train()
```

## Important Note: YMMV

There are many other caveats when it comes to processing that common_voice data, e.g. better resampling and cleaning the data, please do take some time to look at:

- https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper
- https://wandb.ai/parambharat/whisper_finetuning/reports/Fine-tuning-Whisper-for-low-resource-Dravidian-languages--VmlldzozMTYyNTg0

---

## Epilogue

#### Q: Why did you even bother to answer this question?

A: Because I think it's kind of fun and more people should learn to stream the data and learn more about limited computes. Also it democratize the model training to students who wants to tune something but has machine with limited storage.

#### Q: Why don't you just post the link to the docs/blogpost?

A: I guess you mean this https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper, yes that is where I get most of the information for this answer. But I wanted to learn how to tune the model with `streaming=True` too and I learn best by walking through the code and "talking/answering the nagging thoughts in my head"

#### Q: Okay, so the answer could have simply been "See [https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper"](https://huggingface.co/blog/fine-tune-whisper%22)?

A: Yep, but it's still a good exercise for me to write this answer and try the code for myself, while hoping that someone else in the future read this and find it edu-taining =)